# Set height of div

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with a absolute positioned div.

I can't set the height of the div element. Is this an issue or is the mistake somewhere else?

```
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 33px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: What went wrong ? Can you set up a fiddle / snippet of your code and your expectation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for so many answers.

The problem was the content of the div.
`overflow: hidden;` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need a display type set.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working well for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9fmwcp9/1).

```css
#myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 33px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are not inheriting other properties if you are nesting divs.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the div is not empty, if empty please set the width of the div

```css
    #mydiv {
        position: absolute;
        left: 33px;
        top: 20px;
        height: 200px;
        background:red;
       width:20px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Not a requirement, but take a look at the new [Stack-Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1), so you don't have to make a jsfiddle demo